# Prevent starting GcmTaskService twice

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have created a very simple service that updates the user location on the Server:

```
public class LocationSchedulerService extends GcmTaskService {

    @Override
    public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
        // Update to server stuff

        return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I created an simple BootBroadcastReceiver to start the service when the device boots:

```
PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
        .setTag("LocationSchedulerService")
        .setService(LocationSchedulerService.class)
        .setPeriod(LOCATION_UPDATE_PERIOD * 60)
        .setFlex(LOCATION_UPDATE_FLEX * 60)
        .setPersisted(false)
        .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
        .setRequiresCharging(false)
        .setUpdateCurrent(true)
        .build();

GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context).schedule(task);
```

### Now here my question:

Since there is no possibility to know when the user has installed the package i would also like to start this task when the user starts the app. But how do i prevent that the task is running twice?

I read the documentation of [setUpdateCurrent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/Task.Builder#setUpdateCurrent(boolean)) but im not sure about the functionallity. Does it means that the current running service will be cancelled, or its exactly the thing that i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe there is why setUpdateCurrent was introduced - apps wanted a way to "only schedule their task if it didn't already exist"

But what do you mean by "how do i prevent that the task is running twice"? You are scheduling a PeriodicTask, which means that the task will be executed every (LOCATION_UPDATE_PERIOD * 60) seconds.

It sounds like the default setUpdateCurrent=false is what you want, and you schedule the PeriodicTask both on BOOT_COMPLETED *and* in your onCreate() for your app.

If your concern is that on first start you want to immediately update the location, and then default to every LOCATION_UPDATE_PERIOD*60 seconds,  you can write code in onCreate to:
 check for 1st boot (probably write to a shared_prefs file and if the value doesn't exist then you know it's first boot)
    if 1st boot, schedule a special OneoffTask to execute in the next minute. Give this OneoffTask a special tag like "LocationSchedulerService:first_boot"

then in your LocationSchedulerService extends GcmTaskService:

```
public int onRunTask{
    if (tag.equals("LocationSchedulerService:first_boot")) {
        performLocationUpdate();
        // Now that you've done the one time update, fall back to
        // your original schedule

        PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setTag("LocationSchedulerService")
            .setService(LocationSchedulerService.class)
            .setPeriod(LOCATION_UPDATE_PERIOD * 60)
            .setFlex(LOCATION_UPDATE_FLEX * 60)
            .setPersisted(false)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)  // not needed, default
            .setRequiresCharging(false)  // not needed, default
            .setUpdateCurrent(true) // not needed, you know this is 1st time
            .build();

            GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context).schedule(task);
    } else if tag.equals("LocationSchedulerService") {
        performLocationUpdate();
    } else {
        // error
    }
```

By the way, you don't need a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver. The idea of GcmNetworkManager is to allow you to avoid that by setting persisted=true. This way you know that your task will be persisted across reboots.
It is usually sufficient to simply schedule it one time in onCreate.

Comment: Thank you for you very complete answer. Now i removed the BOOT_RECEIVED permission and receiver.

Comment: @PhilipGiuliani you still need the BOOT_RECEIVED permission for GcmNetworkManager to persist your task after a reboot.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation it seems like calling `setUpdateCurrent(true)` will update the scheduling constraints of your `PeriodicTask` with them same tag.

> Optional setter to specify whether this task should override any preexisting tasks with the same tag. This defaults to false, which means that a new task will not override an existing one.

Also you can actually cancel your `Task` before scheduling a new one with [GcmNetworkManager.cancelTask()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager#cancelTask(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService%3E))

Comment: Thanks, im scheduling the job again on every app start (with setUpdateCurrent) and a little side-effect is that its resetting the next execution time back to my LOCATION_UPDATE_PERIOD every time. But thats not a big issue.

Comment: Philip, if you are doing this then you should setUpdateCurrent(false) (actually this is the default).
The idea is that with this you can call schedule() every time your app starts yet *not* push out the period. This is exactly why the setter exists. If the task is not scheduled (first install) then it is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Since your goal is to have the `GcmTaskService` always run, including through reboots, all you need to do is `setPersisted(true)`, rather than false as in the sample code in the question.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/PeriodicTask.Builder.html#setPersisted(boolean)):

> public PeriodicTask.Builder setPersisted (boolean isPersisted)
>
> Optional setter to specify whether this task should be persisted across reboots. This defaults to true for periodic tasks, Callers must hold the permission android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, otherwise this setter is ignored.

So, don't worry about making your own BootBroadcastReceiver, just add the boot permission.

---

Since the main question is about preventing multiple runs of `GcmTaskService` at the same time.. that can be done by just having the same tag for the tasks. By default, if the task (by the same name) is already running, then will happen. By doing `setUpdateCurrent(true)`, the parameters for the task will be updated/replaced when calling `schedule()`.

Source: [PeriodicTask.Builder.setUpdateCurrent(boolean)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/PeriodicTask.Builder.html#setUpdateCurrent(boolean))